# How to pass json data from one javascript to another

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Guys here the first script is designed to take static .json files to display certain content and animate them. The code snippet is

```
     var self = this;
  $.getJSON('data/post_'+ index +'.json', function(d){
    self.postCache[index] = d;
    callback(d)
```

but I want to modify it to so it could take data from database. I got the data in the same format as it was in static json files and my question is how can I pass that data to this script so that it work as it should.

I am sending request using ajax

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                   
      data: "<?php echo $data?>",     
      dataType: 'json',                      
      success: function(data)          
      {
        //I really dont know what to write here :(
      } 
    });

  });
```

and the api.php file is getting data from database and I an encoding the data to json using json_encode

Comment: Does the code in $.getJSON work completely?

Comment: Yes it is working as it should be

Comment: It looks like "index" is the argument for the data.... so for the second function it could be post_id: <?php echo $post_id;?> that way you aren't reusing "data" all of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var self = this;
$.post('api.php',
    {"post_id": index},     
    success: function(d)          
    {
        self.postCache[index] = d;
        callback(d);
    });
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

In api.php do a SQL query where the post_id = $_POST['post_id'] then echo json_encode($database_row);

Comment: The api.php retun a json encoded "string". and I am here googleing and found on various site that 
.getJSON can be used to call .php file with desired data like .ajax

 $.getJSON('json-data.php', function(data) { //rest here}

So can this method work?

Comment: Yes I think you can use $.getJSON('json-data.php', function(data) .... but for the arguments it would be $.getJSON('json-data.php', {post_id: index}, function(data) .... I think the php might receive the argument as $_GET['post_id']

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` just calls `$.ajax` with some predefined values automatically set for you. This means, *since you said the data is the same*, that you can do exactly the same as you were doing previously.

1. Keep a reference to `this`
2. Make your async call
3. in the success function, save your reference and execute your callback

   ```
   var self = this;
   $.ajax({
       url: 'api.php',
       data: "<?php echo $data?>",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data)
       {
           self.postCache[index] = data;
           callback(data);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: success should be function(d) or the code below it should involve the variable "data" instead of "d".